# MVC Action not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Controller :

```
public ActionResult Insert()
{
    return View();
}
public ActionResult Insert(Employee emp)
{
    Employee emp1 = new Employee();
    emp1.insert(emp);
    return View();
}
```

cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Employee", "Insert", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.name)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.mob)

    <input type="button" value="Register me" />
}
```

I have to save my model values on button click ('Register me'). Thanks in advance.

Comment: It needs to be `<button type="submit" ...>` (and I assume your 2nd method has `[HttpPost]`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to set attributes in your controller:

```
[HttpGet] // here ([HttpGet] is default so here you can delete this attribute)
public ActionResult Insert()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]  // here
public ActionResult Insert(Employee emp)
{
    Employee emp1 = new Employee();
    emp1.insert(emp);
    return View();
}
```

To call some action you need to submit your form. Change your `button` to `submit` type:

```
<input type="submit" value="Register me" /> // type="button" -> type="submit"
```

Also, in `BeginForm` you should firstly specify action name and then controller name:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Insert", "Employee", FormMethod.Post))
```

Comment: Also Html.BeginForm("**Insert**", "Employee", FormMethod.Post) ?

Answer (score 3):

Its Because you have not declared `HTTP POST` on `INSERT action`

```
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult Insert(Employee emp)
    {
        Employee emp1 = new Employee();
        emp1.insert(emp);
        return View();
    }
```

When you are using `Beginform` and your `FormMethod` is `Post` the related Action needs to have same kind of HTTP, By the way it doesn't matter if you have `[HttpGet]` on first `ActionResult` Because in MVC, any ActionResult that haven't declared any type of HTTP request/respond are known as `[HttpGet]`

Also in your BeginForm():

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName(Insert)", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.name)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.mob)

    <input type="submit" value="Register me" />
}
```